# Newly created TFS 2010 iteration not visible

Tags: visual-studio-2010, tfs

I've created a new iteration in TFS 2010 and wan't to use it in a new story and query.

However, the iteration won't show up in the new story window, refreshing VS, restarting VS, switching to other project, nothing helps.

I'm a project administrator in the team project, and created the iteration with the same user that i'm trying to use it with. Permissions are not changed from default.
Tested on other workstation with other user with sufficient permissions also doesn't help.

Could I be doing something wrong?

Comment: Are some objects created for this iteration?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Make sure "Team Foundation Background Job Agent" is running on the server hosting your TFS instance and it is running under a service account.  See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms252450.aspx for more information.

Comment: I ended up rebooting the server, and it started working.. so probably this service is involved. Don't check the state before rebooting. Seems odd that a service is involved in something simple as creating a iteration.

Comment: I also had this issue, but the "Team Foundation Background Job Agent" was running when I checked.  I restarted the service just in case, but it did not help.  Rebooting the machine, however, did.

Answer (score 1):

A little bit late but we encountered the same problem.
I tried to restart the "Team Foundation Backgroud Job Agent", without any effect.
But I found a solution, although I am not sure if it is a bug or not.

We are using the Scrum Template for this project, and I have not checked this with any regular Project Template but I quess it is the same. First add the desired new iteration by right clicking on the TFS project and selecting the "Team Project Settings" -> "Areas and Iterations...".

On the Iteration Tab, we have now 2 iterations (at least in our case) with multiple sprints within these iterations. You can add a sample Iteration if you have only one Iteration
After moving the new Iteration downwards, so its new position is beneath the existing Iteration, I was able to see and select the new Iteration in my Team Query. If the new Iteration is already beneath another Iteration, simply move up the new Iteration

This may be a bug, or the use of the Scrum template might interfere with any sync process but the above method worked for us.

Answer (score 0):

In my situation this was caused by an alphabetization issue.  In my Iteration Setup I added '2.11' at the bottom of the iterations and then looked in a Work Item and couldn't see the new iteration.

Turns out the work item template was sorting alphabetically and not obeying the Iteration setup.  So my iteration was always there, it was just between '2.1' and '2.2' instead of where I expected to see it.