# New TFS iteration not available for new work item

Tags: tfs

A while back I upgraded to TFS 2012. Very recently I added a new iteration `9.2.9` to the list of iterations we have in TFS. However, I am not seeing the new iteration available to select in the drop-down list when creating a new development work item. I can't type it in manually either. How do I get the iteration list to synchronize or show the full list as valid options?

**Adding/editing iterations**

[image]

**Selecting an iteration** (Notice `9.2.9` and `9.2.x` do not appear as I would expect them to)

[image]

Comment: Did you look at [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6979130/newly-created-tfs-2010-iteration-not-visible), maybe similar problem occurs despite it is tfs 2010 in the question. And [this](https://blogs.blackmarble.co.uk/blogs/rfennell/post/2008/10/16/tfs-iterations-not-appearing-in-iterationpath.aspx) is another similar issue

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should upgrade to the latest version of TFS. This was a bug in the version of 2012 that you are using. It was fixed in the latest TFS 2012 update, but there is no good reason that you should not go to TFS 2013 Update 4.

Comment: I was all ready to install TFS 2013 Update 5 (apparently released today, by coincidence) so I shut down the machine, created a snapshot, and started it up again. After starting it up, everything started working well again (including the missing iterations). Maybe I'll still try TFS 2013 after I get this pending release out, but for the moment, a reboot was sufficient.

Comment: Initial indications are that TFS 2013 can still work with a TFS 2012 build server. Would you also advise upgrading the TFS build server to stay in sync?

Comment: I would. I would also advise to go strait to 2015 RC2 and use the new build system

Comment: The term "new build system" suggests we might not be talking about mere bug fixes here. This is a product no longer under active development and we don't have any resources to maintain the build process or source control. Am I going to regret upgrading by learning that build scripts will have to be modified, or is it fully backward compatible? Normally I'm among the first to jump to the latest release/technologies around here, but we're actually moving away from Microsoft for project tracking and source control, so I'm hesitant to make unnecessary changes in this area.

Comment: The existing Xaml builds will still work on the existing build infrastructure. What are you moving to and why? Email me!

Answer (score -1):

Rebooting the TFS server resulted in a number of lost emails getting sent, and the missing iterations showing up as well.

Comment: That however is not a solution but a band-aid

Comment: @MrHinsh of course. That's why my comment on the other solution was that I was going to try that one ASAP. But at the moment, this is my solution, much quicker and safer to do on the day of release. I am planning to begin upgrading today now that the release is out.