# Newly created iterations and areas are not synched

Tags: tfs

I am using TFS 2013 update 4:

Scenario:

- Add a new iteration from the administration page of a project.
- Go to the project Dashboard create a new work item.
- Newly created ierations and areas are not shown in the relative dropdowns.

Steps taken:

- Checked the server for errors in the event viewer, no issues.
- Check the 'Visual Studio Team foundation Job Agent' running with no issues under the TFS admin user.
- The newly created iteration exists in the collection database table 'tbl_nodes' and in the 'TFS_Warehouse' Database.
- Checked the Jobs on the database and forced them to start, did not solve it.

What I was not able to do is figure out which table exactly the TFS is querying the nodes from, afterall the Stored procedures are encrypted.

Amemdment:

**the newly created iterations exist in the 'tbl_nodes' but does not exist in 'TreeNodes' table.

Answer (score 1):

Since newly created iterations and areas are both in database. Try to restart **Team Foundation Background Job Agent** service to force synchronization in TFS server.

If it's still not help, give a try with rebooting the server, which may do the trick. You can also take a look *Mark's* solution in this similar issue [Newly created TFS 2010 iteration not visible](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6979130/newly-created-tfs-2010-iteration-not-visible)